# How to use linq-to-sql group by to list duplicated records?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Suppose I have two tables: Category and Product. I want use linq-to-sql to select all categories (with products) that have duplicated products.
My query goes like this:

```
from p in db.Products
group p by p.CategoryId into c
select new 
{
 categoryId = c.Key,
 products = from PbyC in c 
 group PbyC by PbyC.Name into dupl
 where dupl.Count() > 1
 select dupl;
}
```

It works but LINQPad lists empty Categories (without any duplicated Product). How to modify the query?

It would be great to have Category name display somehow instead of Id.

EDIT: I have relationship between tables.

Comment: You're getting Categories with no related Products?  The way I'm reading this query, that shouldn't be possible because you're only querying the Products table...

Comment: Result is IOrderedQueryable<categoryId,IEnumerable<>> . so list of categories ids and nested list of duplicated products. Some categories are in fact empty but are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Products.GroupBy(p => new { p.Name, p.CategoryId })
           .Select(g => new { g.Key.CategoryId, Count = g.Count })
           .Where(ng => ng.Count > 1)
           .Select(ng => ng.CategoryId);
```

That'll select the ids of the categories with more than one Product of the same name, and is assuming you don't have any relationships set up between the objects so you'll need to join the results to the `Categories` table to get detailed info.

If you do have a relationship set up then you can always change the `CategoryId` to `Category` (or whatever the related object is named) and just select `Category.Name` in the last `Select`.

Comment: I have relationship between tables.